# Matlab kernel not adding to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: matlab, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Matlab Kernel and imported matlab engine into Jupyter.

But It is still not showing up under kernel option.

I have also did:

```
export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin
```

Detail:

```
[??? home]$ pip install matlab_kernel
Requirement already satisfied: matlab_kernel in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: metakernel>=0.18.0 in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=4.4.0 in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.tempfile in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>=4.2 in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from metakernel>=0.18.0->matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from metakernel>=0.18.0->matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref in ./ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from backports.tempfile->matlab_kernel)
```

Should I shutdown the matlab notebook and restart it again?
or problem is because of something else?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late. But to not let this unanswered.

I came across the same problem and realised that I was missing to also run:

```
 python -m matlab_kernel install --user
```

The `--user` flag installed in my user path

```
jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
matlab     ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/matlab
python3    ~/anaconda2/envs/matlab16a/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```